# Rust compiler error: future cannot be sent between threads safely required for the cast from X to Y

Tags: mongodb, rust

I have seen other questions about similar errors with implementing send, but my error message is different. This is the error message:

```
future cannot be sent between threads safely
required for the cast from `impl warp::Future<Output = Result<std::string::String, std::string::String>>` to the object type `dyn warp::Future<Output = Result<std::string::String, std::string::String>> + std::marker::Send`
```

I'm getting this on a function on an implementation of an async_trait. Here's the impl:

```
use std::borrow::Borrow;

use async_trait::async_trait;
use mongodb::{
    bson::{doc, oid::ObjectId, Document},
    error::Error,
    options::FindOneOptions,
    results::InsertOneResult,
    Client,
};
use serde::{de::DeserializeOwned, Serialize};

pub struct MessagesRepository<'a> {
    pub(crate) client: &'a Client,
}

#[async_trait]
impl<'a> super::Repository<'a> for MessagesRepository<'a> {
    fn with_client(client: &'a Client) -> Self {
        MessagesRepository { client: client }
    }

    async fn find_one<'b, T: DeserializeOwned + Sync + Send + Unpin>(
        &self,
        filter: Document,
        find_one_options: FindOneOptions,
    ) -> Result<Option<T>, Error> {
        let collection = self
            .client
            .database("App")
            .collection::<T>("Messages");

        collection.find_one(filter, find_one_options).await
    }

    async fn insert_one<'b, T: DeserializeOwned + Sync + Send + Unpin + Serialize>(
        &self,
        new_document: impl Borrow<T>,
    ) -> Result<String, String> {
        let collection = self
            .client
            .database("App")
            .collection::<T>("Messages");

        let result = collection.insert_one(new_document, None).await;

        match result {
            Ok(_) => Ok("Success".to_string()),
            Err(_) => Err("Error".to_string()),
        }
    }
}
```

This is the trait:

```
use std::borrow::Borrow;

use async_trait::async_trait;
use mongodb::{
    bson::Document, error::Error, options::FindOneOptions, results::InsertOneResult, Client,
};
use serde::{de::DeserializeOwned, Serialize};

#[async_trait]
pub trait Repository<'a> {
    fn with_client(client: &'a Client) -> Self;
    async fn find_one<'b, T: DeserializeOwned + Sync + Send + Unpin>(
        &self,
        filter: Document,
        find_one_options: FindOneOptions,
    ) -> Result<Option<T>, Error>;

    async fn insert_one<'b, T: DeserializeOwned + Sync + Send + Unpin + Serialize>(
        &self,
        new_document: impl Borrow<T>,
    ) -> Result<String, String>;
}
```

Anyone have any ideas? I'm using the mongodb rust driver. Thanks!

Comment: Please post the **full** error message, we don't even know where the error occured. And preferrably provide a [mre] without which debugging becomes hard to impossible for others.

Comment: The `new_document` argument probably needs to be `impl Borrow<T> + Send`. You haven't constrained it to be `Send` and the value exists until the future is first polled, before which it would be illegal to send the future across threads, so the future itself can't be `Send`.

Comment: Thank you so much! I was so confused. I added `+ Send` and `+ Sync` and it compiled! I'm confused still on the different between the constraints on the `T` in the type parameter of the `insert_one` function versus the constraints on the `Borrow<T>` of the `new_document` argument. I assumed it was receiving the `T` parameter, but I guess wrapping it in the `Borrow` caused other problems?